# Wordpress - метки как поддомены

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с проблемой.

Нужно чтобы метка открывалась как поддомен, например site.ru?tag=dom было доступно по адресу dom.site.ru

сервер для работы с поддоменами настроен.

```
function sd_category_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {

$url = getenv( 'HTTP_HOST' );// для получения слага метки из урл dom.site.ru
$domain = explode( ".", $url );
$categorystr = $domain[0]; // тут остается только dom



$rules = array();

$rules['$'] = 'index.php?tag='.categorystr;

return $rules;

}

add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'sd_category_rewrite_rules' );
```

Вот почему то если брать слаг метки из урл и передавать его в переменную $categorystr, то ничего не работает.
$categorystr = $domain[0]; //в таком виде ошибка 404

хотя если я сам укажу к переменной слаг метки вот так:
$categorystr = 'dom';
то все работает.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

```
'index.php?tag='.categorystr;
```

наверное нужно:

```
'index.php?tag='.$categorystr;
```